# How can I show the receiver name in a rules email

Tags: rules, emails

I use the rules module in Drupal 7. I use it to send an email to a few receivers with a certain role. How can I get their name or userID? Is there a Replacement Pattern to get the email Receiver details?

edit:

I'm sorry for being unclear. I have made a rule that emails all users with a certain role after new content of a certain type was created. In this email I would like to start with "Hi [Username_of_email_receiver]" but it seems I can only use the author username or the current logged in username

Comment: Hi, could you be more specific? where do you need to get this information about users?

Comment: As I read it you want a Predefined %Name in the email template, taken from the profile field name?!

Comment: I'm sorry for being unclear. I have made a rule that emails all users with a certain role after new content of a certain type was created. In this email I would like to start with "Hi [Username_of_email_receiver]" but it seems I can only use the author username or the current logged in username

Comment: I have editted the question instead of commenting it

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You cannot, the message is the same for all users of a certain role in this case. I think you have, first, to get the users of a certain role (php custom code) and then for each user fire an other rule or a custom hook_mail with the account as argument

Comment: I´ll try to come up with some custom code. thanks for your answer

Answer (score 0):

Couldn't you do fetch entity (type user) by property and have the property by the role and select that role? Then loop through entity list of users and then you can, i believe, access the fields on each user as you loop through.